# How can override the title markup on a node page?

Tags: 7, theming

I've managed to implement a custom page template but it still uses the default title markup.

I'm trying to find out how to replace the markup around the title so I can change it to something like:

```
<h1 class="title" id="page-title">Node title</h1>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
```

Can I override a template like region--header.tpl.php or something similar?

I'm using an omega based custom theme too btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected as soon as I posted this question I found the solution..

If you use the template **region--main-heading.tpl.php** you can override title markup.

Comment: That depends pretty much on your theme. And we still don't know what base-theme you are using. So what worked for you probably doesn't work for others.

Comment: Also region templates shouldn’t contain tag markup, only layout/container elements. This wasn’t a core Drupal issue.